# Should the [latest] and [recent] tags be removed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, meta-tags, burninate-request

I noticed that there is a [latest](/questions/tagged/latest) tag and a [recent](/questions/tagged/recent) tag, I don't think that either really adds anything to the question as they can mean anything from latest file, latest date, latest version of something etc (and the same for recent) based off some of the questions that are tagged with those tags.

Both of them have no tag wiki or followers, should they be removed?

Comment: A quick glance does indeed seem to indicate that there is no value in those tags. Since there are not all that many questions with those exact tags, a manual cleanup (taking care of any other issues at the same time) should be feasible.

Comment: these sound like [meta-tag:meta-tags] and as such, should be removed

Comment: So should I just start going through those posts and removing the tags, or should I wait for a moderator to either weigh in this or do so?

Comment: @Jack, while you probably don't need input from a diamond moderator for this, you should probably give it a full day before taking action, just in case someone has a better idea.

Comment: @Jack And if you end up taking action, don't just remove the tags. Go over the entire post to give it some TLC where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the questions tagged [latest](/questions/tagged/latest) have also been cleaned up, including the general content of the questions which were tagged as such. There was no instance in which the question justified the existence of that tag. The automatic tag cleanup should result in the tag being deleted pretty soon.

Answer (score 2):

All the questions tagged [recent](/questions/tagged/recent) have been cleaned up to the extent possible (bad tags often go hand in hand with bad questions).

That tag could definitely still be blacklisted as it's useless as a tag and bound to recur.